# Woocommerce - Variable product loads default product image before loading actual Variable product image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have woocommerce and i am adding variable products with images. When i wish to open the variable product first it loads the default image/ featured image of product before loading variable products image.
In other way it loads feature image of product and after that it loads image of that variation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding jquery into the footer to load price and image after 5 seconds.